# What is the best way to transfer images from a server to an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, image, data-transfer

What is the best way to transfer images from a server to an iPhone app? Is sending a base64 string faster or sending a link to the image source and then downloading from this source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is sending a base64 string faster`

Definitely not - base64 is, on average, 1.4x larger than binary. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

`or sending a link to the image source and then downloading from this source?`

I'm not sure what you mean here - but two requests when you could simply make one (the request for the image) is also not a good idea.

Simply download the image like normal is the best approach.

You could make sure you're making effective use of caching and GZIP (standard HTTP stuff).

Comment: If I use a JSON API for the data transfer from the server to the iPhone app I have to send the image url so that the iPhone app can download the image. Or is there an other way?

Answer (score 0):

The second option is better than first,it would be better to have http link.

just make sure you load the images just once.